# How do I check the value of an ng-model bound input field programmatically using Ranorex?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, input, qtwebkit, ranorex

We have an input field in html which is bound to a javascript value via [[ng-model]](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel). What we've found is that the text value bound to does not actually appear in the DOM, which seems to be by design.

However, we test certain elements via Ranorex, and we'd like to test this one, and Ranorex doesn't (as far as we know) have access to the Angular scope, only the DOM, via "AccessibleValue".

This would seem to be the same problem we'd have to solve if we wanted to check any user-entered text in Ranorex, we're just not sure how to solve it.

**How do I check the value of an ng-model bound input field programmatically using Ranorex?**

EDIT: We've actually found this is an artifact of running angular inside a QtWebView (in the real world, you can just check the input's value), which means we've got 3 independent programs that we're expecting to behave nicely with each other...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is possible to get the values by using the ExecuteScript() method.
A code sample can be found on the following forum post:

- http://www.ranorex.com/forum/code-snippet-for-executescript-function-with-return-type-t5070.html#p21345

I hope that helps.